What is the relationship between the span of a vector set and the number of free variables?
I am currently taking my first linear algebra college course, and I am trying to grasp the idea of linear dependence and the span of a set of vectors. I am still confused about the span of a collection of vectors in $R^n$ and I hope to get some clarity by the following example:
Given the linear system with vectors: $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$
$$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3+c_4v_4 = 0$$ (0 = zero vector)
Let $c_3$ and $c_4$ be free variables and $c_1$ and $c_2$ leading variables, which means that this homogeneous system has infinitely many solutions.
Question 1: Does this mean that $v_3$ and $v_4$ can be written as a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$?
Question 2: When the answer is yes, then the span of this collection of vectors is equal to the span of $v_1$ and $v_2$. Assuming, $v_1 and v_2$ are vectors in $R^2$, does this mean that the collection of vectors spans $R^2$.
To make question 2 more general: is it a general rule that a collection of vectors spans $R^n$ when there are n linearly independent vectors in R^n. To relate it to my example, there are two free variables and four vectors in $R^2$, so 2 linearly dependent vectors and 2 linearly independent vectors, which would mean that the vector set spans $R^2$. Is this reasoning correct?
Hopefully, someone can help me understand this.
Thank you in advance!

what does "leading variables"   mean?

The opposite of free variable. In my course the term 'leading variable' is used for variables that are no free variable, but are expressed in terms of free variables

alright. What does "free variable"  mean?  Exactly why  do you conclude "which means that this homogeneous system has infinitely many solutions"

A free variable is a variable that we choose a value for and on which the value of the other (leading) variables depends. Since a free variable can have any value in R, the homogeneous system has infinitely many solutions

what book are you using?

Linear Algebra and Its Applications, 5th ed. Pearson International Edition 5th

authors appear to be Lay, Lay, McDonald. Maybe I can find a preview that talks about what they were hoping to accomplish by making distinctions among variables

I see, roughly, what you are talking about. If you return to this, suggest you indicate page numbers in the book for definitions....Next, the idea of free and leading is primarily about row reducing matrices. https://home.cs.colorado.edu/~alko5368/lecturesCSCI2820/mathbook.pdf

Thank you Will for your responses! I think I found a general rule to see whether a set of vectors spans $R^n$: "A set of vectors spans $R^n$ when the set contains a basis of n vectors which are in $R^n$." Is this correct?
